# VALUE do INPUT com data formato Y-m-d, porém ao exibir na tela mostre no formato d/m/Y

Tags: php, html

Atualmente meu INPUT está assim, porém ele printa na tela nesse formato Y-m-d, há algum jeito de fazer com que ele exiba na tela a data no formato d/m/Y porém continue com o valor no formato Y-m-d?

```html
<input type="text" name="data" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" placeholder="Data">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar de eu achar melhor converter o valor...

Você pode criar 2 inputs diferentes. Um com o valor que será apresentado e outro que fica escondido com o valor que será usado.

```
// input escondido 
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"/>

// input que mostra o valor
<input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y');?>" placeholder="Data"/>
```

**Resultado**

```html
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="2018-08-12"/> 
<input type="text" name="" value="12/08/2018" placeholder="Data"/>
```

Você também pode usar o `<input type="date"/>`

```
<input type="date" name="data" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"/>
```

Porém ele é só para versão 5 do `HTML` e o suporte da interface dele é irregular.